# Mic input issue in discord in UBUNTU 20.04 LTS

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones, noise

I moved to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS recently and facing this issue with the input mic now.

Things that I'm using

1. UBUNTU 20.04 LTS dual boot with windows 10
2. External mic along with my headphones
3. LENOVO Y520

ISSUES THAT IM FACING

1. It's picking up even the slightest of sound around the room
2. When I sound test , The input is too loud with a lot of noise
3. Fluctuations in the input

THINGS I TRIED.

1. Adjusted the input volume in DISCORD I kept around 70% input volume - either my sound goes too low or comes with a lot of noise
2. Enabling NOISE CANCELLATION AND ECHO CANCELLATION IN DISCORD SETTINGS -  doesn't do the job
3. I tried adjusting the INPUT SOUND directly from SOUND SETTING IN UBUNTU - Still no change
4. I installed PULSE AUDIO AND ENABLED ECHO CANCELLATION AND MADE IT MY DEFAULT , I'm successfully able to install pulse audio but the problem in DISCORD still remains the same
5. I tried installing Noisetourch with this command

tar -C $HOME -xzf NoiseTorch_x64.tgz

but I'm getting some ERROR that I'm not able to get a response

THINGS I STILL DIDN'T DO

1. I didn't reinstall discord
2. I didn't try alsa mixer

Looking for any noise cancellation software for Ubuntu which also works well with discord
Could someone please find me a fix for this , I'm not able to find a proper answer for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Adjusted the input volume" is vague -- how? In Discord? Alsamixer? Microphone Settings? Somewhere else? There are lots of possibilities. Please edit your question to be completely clear about exactly which screens and commands you used. Remember that your system may look a bit different from ours, so more detailed descriptions help us to understand and help you to get a useful answer.

Comment: Hey there I edited my question , please have a look . I think I have mentioned the important things needed .

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. I lowered down the system input level and limited input sensitivity at about 40-50% on discord. I believe echo is caused by the duplication of inputs (by system and discord inputs) and by increasing sensitivity you basically tell discord to ignore inputs below that threshold while still taking them both in. Hope this helps.